# Which is the correct method of upgrading React Native in your app?

Tags: react-native

In React Native, what is the difference between:

- `react-native-git-upgrade`
- `react-native upgrade`
- `yarn upgrade react-native`
- Just deleting `node_modules`, bumping the version number in package.json, removing yarn.lock or package-lock.json and doing an `npm install` or `yarn install`

What is the preferred method, advantages/disadvantages? Are some outdated? Only relevant for certain versions?

I want to love React Native, but when it comes to versions, it is absolute hell. 0.44.1 is the only version that has consistently worked for me without random fatal errors on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) in the official `react-native` document, the best way for upgrading `react-native` is using `react-native-git-upgrade` if you create your project with `react-native init`. If you started you app with `create-react-native-app` please read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html#create-react-native-app-projects).
 
Because React Native projects built with native code are essentially made up of an Android project, an iOS project, and a JavaScript project, upgrading can be rather tricky.
**Advantage**: The module `react-native-git-upgrade` provides a one-step operation to upgrade the source files with a minimum of conflicts. Under the hood, it consists in 2 phases:

- First, it computes a Git patch between both old and new template
  files,
- Then, the patch is applied on the user's sources.

Comment: When I upgrade via `react-native-git-upgrade` I see the following logging statement: `git-upgrade info Upgrading to React Native 0.49.1, React 16.0.0-beta.5`. Why is this not reflected in package.json? That file is unchanged and still has the previous versions I was using. Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Is your `react-native-git-upgrade` in latest version?

Comment: @VahidBoreiri: Can you please advice? I couldn't seems to find the command `react-native-git-upgrade not found` eventhou I've installed it successfully

Comment: Any of you guys facing this issue? @JohnD.

Comment: sorry I don't have any idea at the moment.

Comment: @Issac did you install with the -g flag? If not, it won't be available globally.

Comment: I used -g for install it.